# Applying TextureView to MediaPlayer after MediaPlayer.prepare causes black screen

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I'd like to switch the video method in `MediaPlayer` to `TextureView`'s `Surface` at some point during playback. But all I get is a black screen (the sound is playing). I made sure the size of the `TextureView` is ok, so it's not the case.

If I set the `Surface` of `TextureView` **before** calling `prepare` on `MediaPlayer`, than the video is shown.

So it seems that the order of calling `prepare` and applying the surface is crucial.

What's interesting, in case of `SurfaceView` everything works fine (no matter when I set the holder of `SurfaceView`: before or after the preparing is done).

Is there a way to set TextureView to MediaPlayer during playback? Calling `MediaPlayer.release()` and recreating it again while having to take care of progress would be very inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {
        s = new Surface(surface);
            Thread play = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        player = new MediaPlayer();
                        player.setSurface(s);
                        player.setDataSource(vidAddress);
                        player.prepare();
                        player.setOnPreparedListener(MainActivity.this);
                        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        player.setOnCompletionListener(MainActivity.this);
                        player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);

                        Log.e("mediaplayer", "true");
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            play.start();

        }
```

And your onPrepared listener like this

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (!player.isPlaying()) {
            player.start();     
        }
}
```

setSurfaceTextureListener like this at onCreate

```
mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(MainActivity.this);
```

I hope this will help :)